# How derived object in base pointer invokes base function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

How can a base pointer holding derived object still point to base function ?
Here After

```
a_ptr = &b_obj; 
a_ptr->disp();
```

If the base function had been virtual i understand the involvement of V-table, which holds the address to base function.But here the base pointer hodling derived object can manage to call the base function.

Can anyone throw some light on what happens behind the scene ?

```
class A
{
 public:
 //virtual void disp()
 void disp()
 { cout<< "From class A\n" << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
 void disp()
 { cout << "From Class B\n" <<endl; }
};

int main()
{
 A a_obj;
 A *a_ptr;

 B b_obj;

 a_ptr = &a_obj;
 a_ptr->disp();

 a_ptr = &b_obj;
 a_ptr->disp();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Base pointer always points to the **base part of derived** object. It doesn't know any information about Derived object members / methods.

If you declare the method `A::disp()` as `virtual`, then only it will be resolved at runtime. It may call `A::disp()` or `B::disp()` based on the object `a_ptr` points to.

In simple words,

1. If you declare a method `virtual` then compiler knows that this
   method has to be evaluated at runtime. Also the method must be  invoked using pointer or reference.
2. If the method is called using an object or if the method is not
   `virtual` then compiler straight away puts the call to the method of
   the static type of the caller.

In your case, the static type of the caller is `A*` and the method is not `virtual`. Thus compiler straight away put the call for `A::disp()`; it doesn't wait for runtime evaluation.

```
a_ptr = &b_obj;  // static type --> typeof(*a_ptr) --> A
                 // dynamic type --> typeof(b_obj) --> B
a_ptr->disp();   // (is A::disp() virtual)?
                 // chooses B::disp() at runtime : chooses A::disp() at compiletime;
```

[Note: Suppose if you make only `B::disp()` as `virtual` and keep `A::disp()` normal method as it is, then you will still get the same results as you are getting now.]